# React-native-firebase firestore Filter

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to filter through multiple attributes for a collection in firestore using `.where`, however this just ends up constantly loading and never reaches the .then() section.

I recently learned Firestore doesn't support multiple attributes. What do you recommend as a work around for this?

```
const fetchIndividualEvents = async ({userData}:any) =>{
    
    // console.log(userData.Preference.AgeRange.max)

    firestore().collection('Events')
    .where('Age', '>=' , userData.Preference.AgeRange.min)
    .where('Age', '<=' , userData.Preference.AgeRange.max)
    .where('Host', '!=' , userData.uid)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapchot)=>{
        console.log(QuerySnapchot.docs[0]._data)
    })

}
```

I tried using Filter, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Firestore *does* support multiple `where` clauses in general, but can only perform inequality filters on one field per query (see [query limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)). In your example you have an inequality filter on both `Age` and `Host` , so that specific combination of `where` clauses isn't supported. If you need this type of query for your use-case, consider using a database that supports it.